# Positive function in a particular interval.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Show that

$f(x)=-4\cdot7^x+5\cdot6^x-5^x+4^x-3^x>0$

for $-\frac{1}{2}\le x<0$. Here is its [plotting](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-4*7%5Ex%2B5*6%5Ex-5%5Ex%2B4%5Ex-3%5Ex%20from%20x%3D0%20to%20-1).

By derivative its become in natural log which is more difficult to solve.
Also I am unable to apply Jensen's inequality.

Comment: Hint: Consider the interval $[-\frac{1}{2},0)$. Does $f$ have a root $x_0 \in [-\frac{1}{2},0)$? If yes, the statement is false. If no, then either $f(x) > 0$ or $f(x) < 0$ for all $x \in [-\frac{1}{2},0]$, right? Proceed from here $\ldots$